# Matching three columns of one file with three columns of another file in perl

Tags: perl, matching

I am trying to match 3 columns of one file( first three columns) with three columns 0,3,4 of second file. I am having problem with the code below:Please help me.Thanks.

```
#!usr/bin/perl
  use strict;
  use warnings;

  my $infile1 = $ARGV[0];
  my $infile2 = $ARGV[1];
  my $outfile = $ARGV[2];

  open (INFILE1,"<", $infile1) || die "Cannot open $infile1:$!\n";
  open (INFILE2, "<", $infile2) || die "Cannot open $infile2:$!\n";
  open (OUTFILE, ">", $outfile) || die "Cannot open $outfile:$!\n";

  my @array1;
  my @array2;
  my @array3;
  my @array4;
  my $_;
  while (<INFILE1>) {
      chomp;
      @array1 = split (' ', $_);
      push (@array2, "@array1\n");
      #print "@array2\n";
  }
  while (<INFILE2>) {
      chomp;
      @array3 = split (' ', $_);
      push (@array4, "@array3\n");
      #print "@array4\n";
  }
  #print "@array2\n";
  #print "@array4\n";
  foreach my $array2(@array2) {
       my @line = split(/\s+/,$array2);
       my $chr1 = $line[0];
       my $start1 = $line[1];
       my $end1 = $line[2];
       #print "$line[0]\n";
  foreach my $array4(@array4) {
       my @values = split(/\s+/, $array4);
       my $chr2 = $values[0];
       my $start2 = $values[3];
       my $end2 = $values[4];
      if (($chr1 eq $chr2) && ($start1 eq $start2) && ($end1 eq $end2)) {
         #print  "$start2\n";
         print  "$chr2\t$start2\t$end2\n";
       }
   }
 }
```

file1.txt few lines are as below:

```
chr10   40095550        40096075
chr10   40102275        40102575
chr10   40139575        40140100
```

file2.txt few lines are as below:

```
chr1    mm10_knownGene  exon    3205904 3207317 0.000000        -       .       gene_id "uc007aet.1"; transcript_id "uc007aet.1"; 
chr1    mm10_knownGene  exon    3213439 3215632 0.000000        -       .       gene_id "uc007aet.1"; transcript_id "uc007aet.1"; 
chr1    mm10_knownGene  stop_codon      3216022 3216024 0.000000        -       .       gene_id "uc007aeu.1"; transcript_id "uc007aeu.1";
```

Comment: Try explaining what a match means for you...

Comment: Like the values of all the three columns of one file should be equal to the three columns of the second file and then it should print out the matching lines.

Comment: Have you tried using a hash?

Comment: No.I am actually using perl after long time....m trying to refresh my memory.sorry.

Answer (score 1):

The solution to your problem here is read [`perldata`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perldata.html) and have a look at the section on `hashes`. These are associative arrays, of key-value pairs.

It makes the vast majority of your code redundant.

```
my %exists; 

while ( <INFILE1> ) {
     my ( $chr, $firstnum, $secondnum) = split; 
     $exists{$chr}{$firstnum}{$secondnum}++; 
}

while ( <INFILE2> ) {
    my ( $chr, $mm, $thing, $firstnum, $secondnum ) = split;
    print if $exists{$chr}{$firstnum}{$secondnum}; 
}
```

I would also suggest that you use 3 argument open with lexical file handles instead.

e.g. :

```
 open ( my $infile1_fh, "<", $infile1 ) or die $!;
```

and then

```
 while ( <$infile1_fh> ) {
```

Because then they're locally scoped rather than globals.